# Calling window.location.reload() in promise catch() block without return statement finishes with Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Can you someone explain to me why this code can be finished with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined` when I have as a last statement `window.location.reload();` in the catch block?

```
changeLocale(locale) {
    return this.get('backend').changeLocale(locale).then((data) => {
            return this.get('backend').doSomethingOther();
        }).catch((e) => {
            if (e && e.errorData && e.errorData[0].errorCode === AUTH_FAILED_ERR_CODE) {
                // if authorizationFailed - change locale cookie and reload
                this._bakeCookie(locale);
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                return Promise.reject();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `changeLocale` does not return a spec-compliant Promise, since it has a `.then` method, but the `.then` doesn't return anything

Comment: ^^ And I can't see the contents of the `catch` handler having any impact on it, as the error is well before that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it returns `Promise.resolve();`

Comment: No way it returns `Promise.resolve`, since `Promise.resolve` *does* return a proper Promise, unlike the code here

Comment: Sorry, in the // do something block other callings another service that returns Promise.resolve(). Something like that `return this.get('backend')....`